# Facebook v2.3 Invalid Scope Rails 4.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am getting an invalid scope error with the new facebook API.

The error:

```
Invalid Scopes: friends_birthday. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions
```

The issue is, I don't request that permission on my app. I only use the default permissions. If I go `App Details > Config App Center Permissions`, my permissions are blank because I'm only using the defaults. Why would get this error, do I have whitelist attributes now?

UPDATE:

`friends_birthday` is required in the omnicontacts gem
https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts/blob/master/lib/omnicontacts/importer/facebook.rb#L16

Comment: Which permissions you ask for are not in `App Details > Config App Center Permissions`. They are in your code

Comment: This particular code is for sending invitations using omnicontacts. No where in my app do I request "friends_birthday", at least not that I know of and I built it. Could be defaulted?

Comment: No it is in your code

Comment: I've run a search (ctrl + f) for my entire site, no friends_birthday found

Comment: Look at the URL in the popup. Does it contain friends_birthday?

Comment: it does, right after user_birthday.  but my initializer scope is this: provider :facebook, ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"],{:scope => "user_birthday",:image_size => 'large', secure_image_url: true}

Comment: Then check the framework and see if it adds it.